# Linux script executing from C++ code with execv fails

Tags: c++, linux, file-descriptor, netcat

I've a very basic Linux script (**/home/scripts/script.sh**):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'a' | /bin/netcat -vv 10.10.10.1 3333
echo "done" > /tmp/result
```

When I try to run it from the shell, it works fine. So script is good (also, **done** is written into /tmp/result file):

```
# /home/scripts/script.sh
10.10.10.1: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [10.10.10.1] 3333 (?) open
AABBCCDDEEF
 sent 2, rcvd 13
#
```

However when I'm trying to run it from C++ code in a foreground daemon:

```
const char **argv = new const char* [3];
argv[0] = "/home/scripts/script.sh";
argv[1] = "/home/scripts/script.sh";
argv[2] = NULL;
execv(argv[0], const_cast<char**>(&argv[1]));
```

For a short time it works good (for 3-5mins).
After that short period the script running fails, nc's return code is 1, and this is the output:

```
10.10.10.1: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [10.10.10.1] 3333 (?) open
Preposterous fd value 17
 sent 0, rcvd 0
```

Why is that fd value is preposterous? My daemon opens some files during the first 3-5 min, maybe netcat is not able to deal with larger numbers as fd?

How shall I overcome on this issue?

Comment: `new` is C++, not C.

Comment: Are you running it in a loop? Maybe the server you're connecting to has a rate limit and you're exceeding it.

Comment: That error message happens when the FD is larger than `FD_SETSIZE`. On Linux this is 1024, I don't know why you're getting it at 17.

Comment: No, no loop. I've already found.. My netcat was enormously old. Look, here is a bugfix from **2007**: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg431255.html

Comment: Why are you using `const_cast`?

Comment: So netcat used to be coded to allow 16 as max fd before 2007, and some debian destros still using that code.

Comment: @hyde: I just have copied it from somewhere, it might be unnecessary.

Comment: If there's no loop, what do you mean by it working for 3-5 minutes?

Comment: What are you doing in the rest of the program that's causing lots of FDs to be allocated?

Comment: @Barmar: this is part of a bigger program, but I believe it does not belong here.

Comment: So the problem happens if the program runs for 3-5 minutes before trying to run `netcat`? Can you set the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag on all the FDs you open? Then when `netcat` starts up, it should get a low-numbered FD and mitigate the problem.

Comment: But a simpler solution would be to get an updated netcat.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was caused by [netcat](https://nc110.sourceforge.io/).

First I did not realized the importance of this message:

```
Preposterous fd value 17
```

This is actually a very important error message of netcat because it was not designed to work with higher fds than 16 by default which is totally acceptable for a simple scripting.

However in multi-threaded environments when netcat gets called, there can be more than 16 fds already used.

[This](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg431255.html) is message from 2007 which updates 16 to 1024 as a bugfix.

Netcat's official webpage is https://nc110.sourceforge.io, and the current version is 1.10, which still defines *FD_SETSIZE* as 16.

The solution was to grab the code, patch it and build it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick answer: In debian I solved this problem installing **netcat-openbsd**.
The default netcat refers to netcat-traditional which still has this bug.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).